# Работа со вторым монитором Java

Tags: java, jframe

Всем привет, как можно добиться того, чтобы java открыла нужное мне приложение на втором мониторе? Ну допустим хочу я запустить блокнот на втором мониторе.

```
GraphicsDevice[] screenDevices = GraphicsEnvironment
    .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
screenDevices[1].setFullScreenWindow(frame);
```

вот так получаю список мониторов и запускаю Jframe на нужном мониторе.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exe();
```

вот так запусткаю само приложение, при активации JFrame.

Проблема в том, что приложение которое я хочу запустить, всегда открывается на том мониторе, где основная программа. Буду весьма и весьма блогодарен за помощь

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    GraphicsDevice[] screenDevices = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    screenDevices[1].setFullScreenWindow(frame);
    frame.dispose();
    System.exit(0);
}
```